# Fade in and fade out Gui texture

Tags: unity

i am beginner in c# that i want have fade-in and fade-out.
i write script but why didn't work:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FADE : MonoBehaviour {
    private var alpha = 1.0; 
    private var fadeDir = -1;
    private Texture2D myGUITexture;
    float fadeSpeed = 0.2;
    int drawDepth = -1000;



    void OnGUI(){

        alpha += fadeDir * fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime;  
        alpha = Mathf.Clamp01(alpha);   

        GUI.color.a = alpha;

        GUI.depth = drawDepth;

        GUI.DrawTexture(Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), fadeTexture);
    }
}
```

Comment: Go through the new GUI provided by Unity. This is legacy GUI.

Comment: Didn't work in what way? You don't provide enough details here to answer the question. Someone would have to take your code and run it themselves, then guess at how you think it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

finally i can resolve my problem.

```
 using UnityEngine;

 public class FADE : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private float alpha = 1.0f;
     private float fadeDir = -1;
     public Texture2D myGUITexture;
     float fadeSpeed = 0.2f;
     int drawDepth = -1000;

     void OnGUI()
     {
         alpha += fadeDir * fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
         alpha = Mathf.Clamp01(alpha);

         GUI.color = new Color(GUI.color.r, GUI.color.g, GUI.color.b, alpha);
         GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), myGUITexture);
         GUI.depth = drawDepth;
     }
 }
```